# move_uploaded_file - failed to open stream - no such file or directory

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

This is my form code:

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type='file' name='newPicture'>
   <button type='submit' name='submit' id='uploadPicBtn'>Upload Photo</button>
</form>
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       if (isset($_FILES['newPicture'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['newPicture'];
            $serverpath = "images/".$file['name'];

            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $serverpath);
       }
    }
?>
```

They both are in the same .php file (index.php).

I get this error:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/anime.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\account-settings\index.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB4E0.tmp' to 'images/anime.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\account-settings\index.php on line 7

What's wrong?

Comment: have you tested that the directory specified actually exists?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
$parent = dirname(__DIR__);
$serverpath = $parent."\\images\\".$file['name'];
```

instead of:

```
$serverpath = "images/".$file['name'];
```

because it searches for the file inside the same folder as the php script.
$parent stores: C:\xampp\htdocs\ (root of the site)